# Find the longest and second longest string from a one dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone help?
I am trying to print out the longest string and second longest string in php

```
function findLongestStringFromArray($array = array()) {

    if(!empty($array)){
        $length_of_arr = array_map('strlen', $array); 
        $maxLength = max($length_of_arr); // find highest value in the array
        $key = array_search($maxLength, $length_of_arr);
        $key2 = array_search(next($maxLength), $length_of_arr);
        return array(
            'length' => $maxLength,
            'postion' => $key,
            'longest-string'=>$array[$key],
            'secondLongest-string'=>$array[$key2]
        );
    }
}
$arrData = array("car", "paper", "pencil", "football", "databases");
print_r(findLongestStringFromArray($arrData));
```

And then i get this error message
`Warning: next() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\lab2.php on line 134
Array ( [length] => 13 [postion] => 4 [longest- string] => databases [secondLongest-string] => car)`

Comment: What should happen if the longest string is 12 chars long and the second longest is 12 chars but the third longest is 11 chars? Return the first two or first and third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. Sort the input array in descending order by `strlen`, and then return the first two elements with `array_slice`.

```
function findLongestStringFromArray($array = array()) {
    usort($array, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
    $longest = array_slice($array, 0, 2);
    return array_combine(['longest-string','secondLongest-string'], $longest);
}
```

---

To include the length and position as well, you'd need to use `uasort` instead of `usort` to preserve the keys.

```
function findLongestStringFromArray($array = array()) {
    uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
    return [
        'length' => strlen(reset($array)),
        'position' => key($array),
        'longest-string' => reset($array),
        'secondLongest-string' => next($array)
    ];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I realized when I edited the question after answering that this doesn't return length and position. I'll edit the answer to show how to include those.